# Remove one item in cart removes all - Ubercart/Webform

Tags: webforms, ubercart

I'm using:

- Drupal: 7-4.1
- Webform: 7.x-4.12
- Ubercart/webform intg: 7.x-3.0
- Ubercart: 7.x-3.8

I am using this wonderful [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_webform) to add products to cart, all works ok, however, when added more that one item to the cart using multiple webform submissions then When I try to remove one item from the cart it says:

> If you remove this product from your cart, all products associated
>   with your form submission will also be removed. Are you sure you want
>   to delete this product?

So my question is; is there a way to remove one single item from the cart without removing all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not with the module itself. You can build a custom module to modify UC Webform Integration to suit your needs. This would involve 3 parts:

1. Implement a `HOOK_form_uc_cart_view_form_alter()` function such that cart **Delete** link for each submission and they have 2 arguments: **cart/delete-form/$NID/$SID**. You may need to [adjust your custom module weight](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/change-modules-weight-by-module-or-manualy) so that it executes after, [`uc_webform_form_uc_cart_view_form_alter()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_webform/tree/uc_webform.module?h=7.x-3.0&id=ca16afbdc44ed5646a77e491bc50c5d837a31fde#n509).
2. Implement a `HOOK_menu()` function that defines the new `cart/delete-form/%/%` path. [`uc_webform_menu()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_webform/tree/uc_webform.module?h=7.x-3.0&id=ca16afbdc44ed5646a77e491bc50c5d837a31fde#n14) should give you an idea how it's done.
3. Implement your own form/submission handler for the `cart/delete-form/%/%`. The function [`uc_webform_submission_delete_products_form()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_webform/tree/uc_webform.module?h=7.x-3.0&id=ca16afbdc44ed5646a77e491bc50c5d837a31fde#n480) & [`uc_webform_submission_delete_products_form_submit()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_webform/tree/uc_webform.module?h=7.x-3.0&id=ca16afbdc44ed5646a77e491bc50c5d837a31fde#n492) should give you an idea how it's done. The key thing here is you'll be adding something like `$wf_sid = arg(3);` and replacing `isset($cart_item->data['webform_sid'])` with `$cart_item->data['webform_sid'] == $wf_sid` so that only the selected submission is deleted instead of all submissions on that form.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I understand your suggestion, its a bit beyond my ability to execute but at least I know its possible.