# How to execute hook_cron after a rule with event Cron maintenance tasks are performed?

Tags: 7, rules, hooks, cron

I have a `rule` with event `Cron maintenance tasks are performed`.

It is executed when a cron run.

I have implemented `hook_cron` in my custom module and I want this hook_cron should be run after that rule is executed.

But the problem is my `hook_cron` executed first and then that `rule` is executed.

Is there any way to run my `hook_cron` after that `rule`?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the weight of your module so that it gets executed after Rules.

See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/13542/6380)  for more details.